# F# - Recursion on list

Tags: recursion, f#

> > Input: [x1; x2; ... ; xn]
> >
> > Output ([x1; x3; ...; xn], [x2; x4; ...; xn], [x3; x5; ...; xn], ....)

What I have so far is:

```
let rec split = function
| x0 :: x1 :: xs -> (x0::xs) :: split(x1::xs)
| _ -> []
```

Which yields:

```
Input: [1;2;3;4;5;6]
Output: [[1; 3; 4; 5; 6]; [2; 4; 5; 6]; [3; 5; 6]; [4; 6]; [5]]
```

I don't quite see how I can build a tuple of lists recursively.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any need for clarification on the question? @glennsl

Comment: Well, it's barely a question at all. More of a statement, with very little context, followed by a question mark. As you point out yourself, the task just doesn't make sense. If you want it to make sense, you have to ask those who assigned it to you. We can't read their minds any more than you can.

Comment: I don't point out that the task does not make sense. Actually, I believe it does (maybe not from a practical point of view, though). The question is how you can build a tuple recursively? I don't see how that question requires reading the teacher's mind

Comment: You can't, because a tuple isn't a recursive data structure. It also isn't a dynamic data type, it has a fixed number of elements. Therefore it does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why u want to do this, and if its some sort of exercise/homework I don't want to give you the answer BUT I will give you a hint, best start with something that does something sort of in the right direction.

This code takes a list and in a very unnecesary convoluted way, recursive returns a tuple of three of them.

```
let rec tripleList : List<'a> -> (List<'a> * List<'a> * List<'a>) = 
    function 
    | []    -> ([],[],[])
    | (x :: xs) -> 
        let (tail1,tail2,tail3) = tripleList xs
        (x :: tail1,x :: tail2,x :: tail3)

> tripleList [1..10];;
val it : List<int> * List<int> * List<int> =
  ([1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10], [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10],
   [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10])
```

you don't need to do the whole thing as a single function either, you could create 3 functions, 1 that builds each part of the tuple, and then a fourth function that calls the 3 functions to assemble the answer. That may be a simpler place to start.

So a similar sort of thing would be...

```
let rec tripleList1 : List<'a> -> List<'a> = 
    function 
    | []    -> []
    | (x :: xs) -> 
        (x :: tripleList1 xs)

let rec tripleList2 : List<'a> -> List<'a> = 
    function 
    | []    -> []
    | (x :: xs) -> 
        (2 * x :: tripleList2 xs)

let rec tripleList3 : List<'a> -> List<'a> = 
    function 
    | []    -> []
    | (x :: xs) -> 
        (3 * x :: tripleList3 xs)


let tripleList : List<int> -> (List<int> * List<int> * List<int>) = 
    fun xs -> 
        (tripleList1 xs,tripleList2 xs,tripleList3 xs)
```

I prefer the first approach, but both are perfectively valid, and makes the distinction between the need for recursive functions to create the recusrive data structure List<'a>, whilst the tuple just requires a simple standalone function

so maybe try to write a function that takes.

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] -> [1,3,5,7]

and then see if you can generalise that, and then assemble the pieces in another function

(note don't be misled by my example, they have the right structure but they fundamentally don't do what you need, you need to filter out values somehow in each part)